# Access token retrieved from Azure using OAuth2 does not contain permission

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, bearer-token

I am working on a solution that needs to retreive email from a mailbox from a tenant using MS Graph API.
The solution needs to run in the background, with no use input (eg call login page for email in browser)
I have registered an Azure application, and have Admin consent for the MS Graph API:
[Api permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbDie.png)

My VB code is as follows (client_id, client_secret, tenant has been removed as confidential):

```
Dim http As New Chilkat.Http
Dim req As New Chilkat.HttpRequest

Dim json As New Chilkat.JsonObject

' Use the application ID for the client_id.
' (In Azure App Registrations, use the Application (client) ID)
req.AddParam(client_id, )
req.AddParam(client_secret, )
req.AddParam(tenant, )

req.AddParam(scope, https://graph.microsoft.com/.default)
'req.AddParam(username, )
'req.AddParam(password, )
req.AddParam(grant_type, client_credentials)


Dim resp As Chilkat.HttpResponse
' Replace {tenant} with your tenant ID, such as 112d7ed6-71bf-4eba-a866-738364321bfc.

resp = http.PostUrlEncoded(https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token, req)


If (http.LastMethodSuccess True) Then
Debug.WriteLine(http.LastErrorText)
Exit Sub
End If


Dim statusCode As Integer = resp.StatusCode
Debug.WriteLine(response status code: statusCode)
Debug.WriteLine(response body:)
Debug.WriteLine(resp.BodyStr)
```

I can see the above connecting to the Azure app. However, no permission (scope) is returned in the access token.
When I connect to MS Graph via browser, the token has all the required scope.
Can you please help/advise why I am unable to retreive token with permissions from the MS Graph API in vb?

Comment: you have to add the scope in your request.

Answer (score 0):

> Please **note** that, you cannot get **`scp`** claim in the token, as
> user is not involved in generating token from **client_credentials
> grant type**.

I assigned the same **API permissions** to my application like below:

[image]

When I decoded the access token(generated using **client credentials grant type**), `scp` claim is not present in the token like below:

[image]

> You have to use **authorization code flow** grant type to get
> **`scp`** claim in the decoded token, where user interaction is involved.

When I decoded the access token generated using **authorization code flow**, got `scp` claim successfully in the token like below:

[image]

To know more about authorization code flow, please **refer** below link:

[Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a client_credentials flow, which is an app-only context authentication.

The scp claim is only for user based authentication.

If you want to use the client_credentials flow, you **will need to grant Application permissions** on your app registration, instead of Delegated.

These applications permissions will then be present inside a roles claim. You can check the description of these claims here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens

[image]